# How to convert Bytes that contains my data as string?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm receiving data in my server like this:

```
while True:
    data = conn.recv(2048)
    print('data recv = ', data, 'tipo =', type(data))
```

Which results in :

```
data recv =  b'\x01\x00K\x01\x00\x1c\xcc\xb4\xa8\xd4396225413871526\x00\x01Z\x00\x00]$\xcb\x17\x03\x00\x0b\x03\x16\xd1\x05+)\xf8\x00\x00\x00\x05\x02\x00\x1b1.7775626902878214,14:12:32' tipo = <class 'bytes'>
```

The last bit of the result starts after "\x1b1", finishing after the datetime. This data lenght is variable, so I believe converting to a string and counting characters is not the best solution.

Trying to decode 'data' with .decode('utf-8') gives me the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8: invalid start byte
```

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the output supposed to be an english string? Or a different language such as: `ŋᰀ듌풨㤳㈶㔲ㄴ㠳ㄷ㈵6威⑝់̋턖⬅Ԁㄛ㜮㜷㘵㘲〹㠲㠷ㄲⰴ㐱ㄺ㨲㈳`

Comment: Try using `.decode('utf-16')`

Comment: Hi! The output is supposed to be english, yes. I believe it is possible it also contains the hour of reception. I'm going to try to decode 'utf-16' and I'll let you know if it was successfull; Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Got the same output with utf-16. Being : "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x30 in position 76: truncated data"

Comment: If you don't know the format of the data bytes received, you're not going to get very far.  It's definitely  not UTF-8.  It looks like a mix of binary and ASCII data.  For example, the portion `\x1b1.7775626902878214,14:12:32` looks like a length in bytes (\x1b == 27 decimal) and then a 27-byte string.

Comment: I asked the person who sent me the data but the answer will probably come tomorrow or after. That's the whole point I asked, to see if someone knows. No need to be sarcastic or question why the hell I don't know the format. Thanks for the useful information, Mark.